# How to replace a letter of string at some position

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell

Suppose I want to replace the nth letter of some string, how can I do that?

I tried something like this but it's not correct:

```
#!/bin/bash
index= # let say 2
s='Hello'
echo ${s/$index/'a'} # This should print Healo
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) that shows you how to do substring and concatenation.

Let's say:

```
#!/bin/bash
index=2
s=Hello
echo ${s:0:index-1}a${s:index}
```

Comment: Does not work if index=0 but this is your homework. (And index > len(s) )

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `sed`:

```
$ echo "hello" | sed 's/\(.\{2\}\)./\1a/'
```